# twilio short code / two factor Twitter

Tags: twitter, sms, twilio, two-factor-authentication

Question. We want to associate our twitter account with a Twilio number. The program has been written to accept and send SMS messages to a group of people - and it works.  But we can't we can't activate the number with our Twitter account, because Twilio can't send to short codes?   Is there any way to go around this?  Or make it work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio doesn't work with short codes unfortunately. See their documentation on this here.

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-my-twilio-number-send-sms-to-a-non-twilio-short-code